# Cannot read property 'dock' of undefined Nightmare.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, nightmare

This is my code.I am trying to scrape a website using nightmare.js. But whenever i run this code i get an error. I have stated the error below.

```
const { csvFormat } = require('d3-dsv');
const Nightmare = require('nightmare');
const { readFileSync, writeFileSync } = require('fs');
const numbers = readFileSync('./tesco-title-numbers.csv',
  {encoding: 'utf8'}).trim().split('\n');

const START = 'https://eservices.landregistry.gov.uk/wps/portal/Property_Search';
const getAddress = async id => {
  console.log(`Now checking ${id}`);
  const nightmare = new Nightmare({ show: true });
  // Go to initial start page, navigate to Detail search
  try {
    await nightmare
      .goto(START)
      .wait('.bodylinkcopy:first-child')
      .click('.bodylinkcopy:first-child');
  } catch(e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
  //***********************
  // Type the title number into the appropriate box; click submit
  try {
    await nightmare
      .wait('input[name="titleNo"]')
      .type('input[name="titleNo"]', id)
      .click('input[value="Search »"]');
  } catch(e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
  //***********************
  try {
  const result = await nightmare
    .wait('.w80p')
    .evaluate(() => {
      return [...document.querySelectorAll('.w80p')]
        .map(el => el.innerText);
    })
    .end();
  return { id, address: result[0], lease: result[1] };
} catch(e) {
  console.error(e);
  return undefined;
}
//***********************************
};

//working of app begins here
getAddress(numbers[0])
  .then(a => console.dir(a))
  .catch(e => console.error(e));
```

This is the output that i get:

```
PS D:\web-scraping2> node app.js
Now checking HP431696
Nightmare runner error:

    TypeError: Cannot read property 'dock' of undefined
        at Object.<anonymous> (D:\web-scraping2\node_modules\nightmare\lib\runner.js:58:29)

        at Object.<anonymous> (D:\web-scraping2\node_modules\nightmare\lib\runner.js:652:3)
        at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
        at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
        at Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
        at run (bootstrap_node.js:431:7)
        at startup (bootstrap_node.js:155:9)
```

I have installed node-dock, runner-js modules but still it doesn't work. I have also updated my nodeJS to its latest version. I am using the windows terminal to execute my code.

Comment: So i checked the runner.js file and i found this written just above line 58 : "app.dock is not defined when running electron in a platform other than OS X."  as a comment. I think this is the reason for the error. Since  i am running a windows platform what is the solution?

Comment: So i found the problem and it was because i was using the terminal inside the atom ide (the platform-ide-terminal) package.

Comment: Thank you so much for commenting your solution!  Probably saved me at least an hour of troubleshooting.  Maybe much much more.